# Error al actualizar un campo unique

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un problema al actualizar la información de un rol. En mi base de datos tengo el atributo `nombre_rol` como `unique`. Al registrar un nuevo rol funciona perfectamente pero al actualizar el mismo registro me lanza el error de que el elemento Rol ya esta en uso.

**Modelo Rol**

```
class Rol extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rol';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idrol';
    public $timestamps =false;

    protected $fillable =['nombre_rol, descripcion, estado, fecha'];
    protected $guarded =[];
}
```

**RolRequest**

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre_rol'=>'required|unique:Rol,nombre_rol',            
            'descripcion'=>'required'
        ];
    }
```

Estoy usando laravel 5.2 y según la documentación dice que para ignorar debo colocar lo siguiente
`'email' => 'nombre_rol'=>'required|unique:Rol,nombre_rol,'.$user->id.',user_id',`

Pero en mi caso obtengo un error de variable indefinida, ni siquiera entiendo de donde obtengo la variable $user->id.

Comment: ¿O sea que utilizas la misma validación para creación y edición? ¿Es posible entonces cambiar el nombre del rol al momento de editarlo/actualizarlo?

Comment: Sí, uso la misma validación, ¿debería utilizar otra? .En el caso que registré mal la descripción del `rol`, entonces deseo actualizarla se supone que debería actualizar solo la `descripción` pero me marca el error de que el `nombre_rol` ya esta en uso.

Comment: Según tu diseño puedes usar la misma u otra validación, lo que necesitaría saber es si el nombre del rol también se puede modificar, o solo la descripción.

Comment: Bueno obviamente el nombre_rol se puede actualizar en caso de alguna falta ortográfica o algo, pero si yo necesito actualizar únicamente la descripción del mismo , al guardar se reenvía también el nombre de rol sin editar y causa el conflicto  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando los valores incorrectos en la sintaxis de la validación:

- El tercer parámetro es el ID o la llave primaria del registro específico que no se desea incluir en la comparación "unique".
- El cuarto parámetro es el nombre del campo de la llave primaria

En tu caso debería ser algo así, asumiendo que no estés usando Model Binding:

Si tu ruta es algo como `Route::put('actualizar-rol/{id}', 'Controlador@metodo');`

Entonces la validación sería

```
'nombre_rol'=>'required|unique:rol,nombre_rol,'. $this->id .',idrol',
```

---

Si usas Route Model Binding, sería algo así:

Ruta: `Route::put('actualizar-rol/{rol}', 'Controlador@metodo');`

y la valicación:

```
'nombre_rol'=>'required|unique:rol,nombre_rol,'. $this->rol->idrol .',idrol',
```

Comment: Amigo gracias por su respuesta bueno la ruta es la siguiente `{!!Form::model($rol,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=>['acceso.update',$rol->idrol]])!!}` mi formulario contiene estos dos únicos campos `nombre_rol` y `descripcion` y la validación la dejo como usted muestra `nombre_rol'=>'required|unique:rol,nombre_rol,'. $this->rol->idrol .',idrol',` pero al enviar el formulario ahora muestra el siguiente error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Entonces a mi parecer no encuentra el idrol que le envío en la ruta o no sé como tomarlo, a hora se me ocurrió agregar al formulario un input de tipo hidden y enviar el `idrol` y en la validación `'nombre_rol'=>'required|unique:rol,nombre_rol,'.$this->idrol .',idrol',` y funcionó :D .. pero no se si es la forma correcta. gracias

Comment: ¿cómo está definida la ruta en el archivo de rutas? el id ya lo estás enviando como parámetro en la URL, por lo cual es redundante e innecesario dicho campo oculto.

Comment: `Route::resource('/acceso', 'AccesoController');`

Answer (score 1):

Me funciono al 100% usando la validación dentro de mi método update, ya que en mi método store no mando el id.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'type_id' => 'required',
        'owner_code' => 'required|max:6|unique:owners,owner_code,'. $id.',owner_id',
        'name' => 'required|max:50',
        'country_id' => 'required',
        'company_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    $owner = Owner::findOrFail($id);
    $owner->type_id = $request->get('type_id');
    $owner->status = $request->get('status');
    $owner->owner_code = $request->get('owner_code');
    $owner->status = '1';
    $owner->name = ucwords($request->get('name'));
    $owner->country_id = $request->get('country_id');
    $owner->company_id = $request->get('company_id');
    $owner->update();
    return Redirect::to('/owner/'.$id);
}
```

Dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve.
Saludos.